# how does a etag work in expressjs

Tags: express, cache-control, etag, if-modified-since

Expressjs automatically send etags. I would like to know how the etag is generated..is it based on the content that is generated dynamically by the get routine. or is there way I can mainpulate it, by not even going through the process of generating the content(dynamic content - from DB) and pass back etag as same.

may be a middleware which start with just checking if it is valid session id and pass back the same etag that the client gives or may be based of the url + session id..that way it will be unique. and end the request there rather going through the whole db call and all those stuff. in which case I would need to know the client is making a 304 call.

I could go with the expires tag.but when the session is over. if somebody is opening the url it should not allow. so I am thinking the etag should be based of the session id as well. how does if modified can work in this dynamic content scenario. can it be used.

Comment: Can you please clarify your second and third paragraphs? It would be good to get more detail on your particular problem.

Comment: I read your question fives times, and provided a detailed answer about what Etag is below, for people who land here.

In your particular case, I think you confused four concepts: Etag, SessionId, Authentication, Authorization.  I would stroooooongly recommend not reusing any of these for others.   And keep in mind that "premature optimization is the root of all evil!" -- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084

Answer (score 133):

Let me explain it in 2021, with updated information and links to the code.

It's a relatively straightforward and simple (no rocket science) concept, but, at the same, a very tricky thing that as a developer you should really know before it comes to bite you!

## What is Etag?

So, Etag (per [Wikipedia/Etag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)), is a HTTP header.

It can be seen on the "Response Headers" section of some **GET** calls in the DevTools, like the screenshot below.

[image]

In Express, it can start with `W/` (weak, **default**) or not (strong), and then `<LEN>-<VALUE>`, where VALUE is 27 characters long, and LEN is the length of VALUE in hex. ([Source code in June 2021](https://github.com/jshttp/etag/blob/master/index.js#L57))

## What's the purpose of Etag?

Ah, good question. The answer is: Caching!

(PS. And only caching of the Network Traffic between the client and the server.  That's the transmission of the response data, being sent over HTTP(S) to the client; not any sort of internal caching of Server to DB or what not.)

### Caching, how?

The mechanism is relatively simple.

Let's say a client (browser, like Chrome) makes a call to `https://myserver.com/user/profile/get` endpoint and gets a big JSON response of all the profile data of the current user (say, 30 fields of name, phone, photo URL, blah, blah).  Besides handing the response, as a JSON object, to your application, the client, in its own private internal Network layer, will store this data in a client-side cache of `{'https://myserver.com/users/profile/get': <this-json-response-object> }`.

Now, the next time (even days and sessions later) the client is about to make a call to the same endpoint of `.../user/profile/get`, it can tell the server that "*Hey, I have this <previous_json_from_the_cache> in my cache, so don't send it over if what you are going to send is exactly this.*"

### Cool, but isn't that inefficient?

It is!

The problem is if the client sends the entire JSON object from the cache, in the request to the server, it's both a security risk, and quite inefficient -- the same 30-field JSON object is sent over the network, even maybe twice!

What happens here is, the client (i.e. Chrome browser) can compute a hash (say MD5, which is both non-reversible and shorter) and in the second request say "H*ey, if MD5 hash of the JSON you are going to send me back is this `<computed_hash>`, I already have it! so don't send it over.*"

Now, what happens is, the server is going to compute the response (pull from DB and everything), exactly as before.  But, **ONLY RIGHT BEFORE SENDING THE RESPONSE DATA**, it computes the hash value of the response (in server side) to see if it matches what client has said it already has.  If so, it sends a 304 HTTP status response code, instead of 200, which means "nothing is changed."

### Nice! Is it exactly this?

Well, in the example above, if you pay close attention, the Hash Computation is happening both in client side and in the server side.  It would make it hard to change the algorithm, at least.  So, in reality, the "hash of the response" is actually computed only in the Server Side in the first time as well, and will be sent back to the Client.

This computed hash of "the current response," which comes back with the response, is in `ETag` header of the **response**.

With that, whenever client receives a response, it will store: `{ ".../profile/get": [<ETag>, <JSON-Response-Data>] }` in its internal cache.

Then, in any future requests, the client will send this `ETag` value to the server (in some headers like `if-none-match`), to imply that it can receive a 304 if the new call's response is going to have an `ETag` of this.

So, to recap:

- `ETag` value is nothing crazy, but a non-reversible, short, and fast hashed value of the Response Data (body).
- Server sends `ETag` header in **Response** to Client.
- Client sends `if-none-matched` header (with its value being previously received `Etag` values from server) in **Request** to Server.

---

## Great! How can I use it?

By default, it's happening in Express.js.  So, sit back and enjoy!

It's very unlikely that you need to mess up with its settings.

## When should I ever NOT use Etag?

Ah! Welcome to my life. :D  That's how I got here and did all this research.

Express package [uses](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/utils.js#L280) the [etag package](https://github.com/jshttp/etag) (it's just one file, managed by the same guys) to generate the ETag value.  Internally, the `etag` package [uses](https://github.com/jshttp/etag/blob/master/index.js#L46-L50) `sha1` encryption of the **body**, and nothing crazy, to keep the performance at its best. (If you imagine, this function will be called a lot! At least once or twice on average per *any* GET call the server receives and processes.)

To decide whether it should do a 304 or 200, when client has said "*I have these values in my cache already*", Express uses [fresh package](https://github.com/jshttp/fresh) (again only one file, in fact just one function returning a boolean, maintained by the same guys).  Internally, the `fresh` packages reads `if-none-matched` tag of the request headers (`reqHeaders['if-none-match']`) and [compares](https://github.com/jshttp/fresh/blob/master/index.js#L36-L67) it with the `etag` of the response (`resHeaders['etag']`) that it's about to send out.

### Cool, what's the problem then?

The problem arises when your architecture and the communications between client and server rely on custom headers!

For instance, you want to renew the auth or session token on any request, and refresh it in the background and send a new one, as a RESPONSE HEADER on some  requests.

**CURRENT Etag IMPLEMENTATION OF EXPRESS, ONLY RELIES ON RESPONSE BODY, AND NOT RESPONSE HEADERS.**  Even, the custom function that they allow putting in place ([doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#etag.options.table), [code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/response.js#L200-L201)) is only taking body content, and not response headers.

So, what happens is, when the response (e.g. profile data) is not changed, your client might reuse an outdated auth-token and kick the user out due to an invalid auth/session tag!

## How can I disable it?

You can do `app.set("etag", false);` so Express stops sending it.  Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56795825/), you can/should also use [nocache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nocache) via `app.use(nocache())` to also send "Hey Client, don't ever bother yourself caching it!" headers to the client, from the server.

Cheers!

### PS. Final Notes:

- If you think about it, ETags are very valuable for assets (when the size of the response data is like 100KB or more), but not for common API Endpoints data.  So, disabling it for your small-response endpoints might not be a bad idea -- it might worth not paying the overhead, actually.

Comment: This is an amazing answer. Thank you for writing up all the details. Very helpful. I'm also wondering if a backend developer could override the caching on lets say one response, but not disable the caching / Etag for ALL of express.

Comment: @gimp3695 yes you can. If it's Node.js, then you can have separate routes for it and set that manually on response.

Comment: Very detailed, extremely useful answer. Thank you @Aidin

Comment: One of the best answers I've read on SO. Cheers!

Comment: Great answer! Anyway a proper way to disable ETag should be mention, cause now you can only override it's value (set new ETag header value in middleware). If you run - app.set('etag', false); - or - app.disable('etag'); - images/css will still have Etag.

Comment: When you send custom headers with 304, the browser will update the value of the header in it's local cache. BUT if you send the header on the first response (the one that returns 200 OK, and gets cached), but don't return the header at all in the second response (the 304 one), then the old value will be reused.
see: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7234.html#freshening.responses 
"use other header fields provided in the 304 (Not Modified) response to replace all instances of the corresponding header fields in the stored response."

Answer (score 60):

At the time of writing (8th July 2014), weak ETags are generated using [CRC32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) ([source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3ffceff3ed356a711fce5fee6ed00a03f43affd8/lib/utils.js#L53)) and strong ETags are generated using MD5 ([source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3ffceff3ed356a711fce5fee6ed00a03f43affd8/lib/utils.js#L28)).

[Based on what one of the contributors to Express says](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/2129#issuecomment-43965315), you can specify whether to use the strong or weak ETags by:

```
app.enable('etag') // use strong etags
app.set('etag', 'strong') // same
app.set('etag', 'weak') // weak etags
```

It looks like you can also specify your own custom function to do the ETags like so:

```
app.set('etag', function(body, encoding){ /* return valid etag */ });
```

The NPM package [fresh](https://www.npmjs.org/package/fresh) is also worth looking at, as it's used in Express for freshness checking ([source1](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.fresh), [source2](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/e6eeec3f0392f32271309e92aec965b00bbb777d/lib/request.js#L406)).

As for your application, remember that you can override any response headers e.g. `res.set('etag', 'my-awesome-etag-value')` before invoking `res.send()` (or similar function). Further discussion (including advantages and disadvantages) can be found here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/2129#issue-34053148

Comment: I'll like to point out that according to the express 4.X [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set), the default etag type is `weak` when enabling etags.

Comment: Update: ETag generation is done by to the [jshttp/etag](https://github.com/jshttp/etag) module. Version 1.7 (2015-06-08) always uses MD5 instead of CRC32 because CRC32 is prone to collision. The next version will always use SHA1 instead of MD5 because MD5 is not FIPS-compliant. Finally, the only thing "weak" does is set the "W/" prefix on the ETag. While express defaults to "W/", it's technically a strong ETag because the hash is calculated on the body bytes as opposed to its semantic content. If you're able to implement weak ETag calcs for your app, it's a potentially big perf boost.

Comment: Great 2014 answer!  For a 2021 answer, with muuuch more details, see the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for the concise yet detailed explanation.  I wrote my own webdav server in nodejs and it works well, but would like to support the etag.  This makes sense to me.  Hopefully come back and tell you if it works.  Not using Express, all vanilla.  Needed to know how etag works.  This came up.  Kudos!